# android 4.4 - webview don't accept css width 100%

Tags: android, css, webview

I has a problem with the new implementation of webview for android 4.4+.

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://s.videos.globo.com/p2/j/api.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        #player-wrapper, #image-wrapper {
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #image-wrapper {
            z-index: 999;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player-wrapper"></div>
    <img id="image-wrapper">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = document.getElementById('player-wrapper');
        var image = document.getElementById('image-wrapper');

        var player = new WM.Player({
                        autoPlay: true,
                        width: 640,
                        height: 360
                    });

        player.attachTo(element);

        image.onclick = function() {
            player.playVideo();
            image.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

But the rule width: 100% is not working, the # player-wrapper is getting bigger than the webview. Strange that only the #player is being affected, #image are right.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the WM.player constructor, which sets the width of the player to 640px, which is probably bigger than your viewport.  There is no parameter for max-width in the WM.Player constructor, so you'll have to use a meta tag.  Trying adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640px">` in the head section of your HTML so that the viewport is sized to fit the 640px width set in the WM.Player constructor.

Comment: the same HTML works fine in android 4.3, and I tried set the viewport and don't works too

Comment: found this nice snippet which might help `document.body.style.zoom = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio`

Comment: it don't works 100% because the zoom don't fits the webview but was a good start.
The question is: how can I set width and height of an element to 100% in new implementation of webview?

Answer (score 0):

This html tag might be useful.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```